# Represent multiplicity in java with less coupling

Tags: java, oop

Consider two classes Team and Players.

```
Class Player
{
String name;
int age;
//Getters and Setters
}
```

What is the best way to represent a team of players.

1)

```
 Class Team
    {
    String teamName;
    String city;
    List<Player> players;
    //Getters and Setters 
    }
```

2)

```
Class Team
        {
        String teamName;
        String city;
        //Getters and Setters 
        }



Class TeamPlayers
{
Team team;
List<Player> players;
//Getters and Setters  
}
```

The first form seems more logical for me, but the latter one gives more flexibility.
So which one I can decide and what possible pros and cons of both of these approaches.

Comment: I prefer the first.  It requires one less object, makes your table structure easier (if you will have one), and shows the One-to-Many relation much better.  The only reason I would consider the second was if I need to include meta data along with the relation that I don't necessarily want included with the Team.

Answer (score 4):

It depends (of course...)!

If u are going to implement a lot of methods which perform some actions directly on `List<Player> players;` **AND** some methods which do something with `Team` class, it will be more readable to use another class `TeamPlayers` and do some wrappers (if needed) to `TeamPlayers` methods inside `Team` class.

Answer (score 1):

When working with OOP code, I find that the best approach is always the one that models the problem most intuitively.

When you look at a `Team`, it definitely has `Players`. A `Team` should almost certainly know about the players in it, as well as provide functionality for modifying its roster (i.e. `addPlayer()`, `removePlayer()`) - the first option would let this be done easily.

If you require the additional flexibility of the `TeamPlayers` class, you could have the `Team` contain an instance of it and then have the calls to any `Player` related calls to `Team` be delegated to `TeamPlayers`. My two cents.

Comment: Yes, but if I want to  add some more attributes, common to both from the latter it is straightforward just by adding it in team players, how can we attain the same team directly holding the instance of player.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? I don't think I'm understanding it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think using generics will be good here

```
public class Team<T>{

List<T> members = new ArrayList<T>();


}
```

This way you can form any kind of team.

From your code, 
I would prefer first option as it `HAS-A` relationship and multiplicity.

Comment: Not your downvoter, but wouldn't your way introduce a bit more dependance?  Once you say that your team is made up of a specific collection, it becomes less extensible.  What if you want your team to be made up of players that might not share a parent object?  Well, then you COULD add another ArrayList of those objects, but your <T> becomes meaningless since, yes, it is made up of <T>s (Players probably in this case) but also whatever else makes up the team.  I feel like a template team is redundant.